# What does the sleep command do when run in background?

Tags: terminal, background-process, sleep

When I run this command - `sleep 10` the terminal waits for 10 seconds. So `sleep` is acting on the terminal. What happens when I do - `sleep 10 &`? In the first case it was acting on the terminal but in the background what is it doing? Particularly what thing `sleep` is trying to put to sleep?

Comment: `sleep` is not acting on the terminal. When `sleep` is in the foreground, it is a child of the current shell, which waits for *any* foreground child to exit before it then reads (and processes) the next command. Same deal in a script too.

Answer (score 1):

While `sleep` will run in background, it will do nothing for its intended purpose, which is to delay another task in a script.

Example:

`echo "foo" && sleep 10s && echo "bar"`

Will print foo, wait 10 seconds and then print bar. The second `echo` will wait until sleep has exited and only start executing if it ran successful.

`echo "foo" && sleep 10s & echo "bar"`

Will print foo, invoke `sleep`, which will get send to background and immediately execute the second `echo`, because there is no process in foreground it needs to wait for.